# ElasticSearch Indexing, Merge Size too large

Tags: elasticsearch

I posted about ES Data auto-deleting but didn't find a proper solution but now what concerns me is Merge Size. I am running ElasticSearch on a production website has around 100,000 docs and not many queries but what i do is , _update doc, increment its custom_score whenever user clicks on it (PHP Stuff).

My Total ES Size is ~123MB 
and here is the status

```
{
  index: {
    primary_size: 122.5mb
    primary_size_in_bytes: 128518629
    size: 232.6mb
    size_in_bytes: 243931154
  }
  translog: {
    operations: 368
  }
  docs: {
    num_docs: 112263
    max_doc: 113319
    deleted_docs: 1056
  }
  merges: {
    current: 0
    current_docs: 0
    current_size: 0b
    current_size_in_bytes: 0
    total: 1507
    total_time: 6m
    total_time_in_millis: 364562
    total_docs: 12950730
    total_size: 6.3gb
    total_size_in_bytes: 6817241817
  }
  refresh: {
    total: 26154
    total_time: 1m
    total_time_in_millis: 61128
  }
  flush: {
    total: 234
    total_time: 1.5m
    total_time_in_millis: 91111
  }
  shards: {
    0: [
      {
        routing: {
          state: STARTED
          primary: true
          node: 4klrp2F7TXqbqV2i2uJlrg
          relocating_node: null
          shard: 0
          index: tune
        }
        state: STARTED
        index: {
          size: 32.4mb
          size_in_bytes: 34065166
        }
        translog: {
          id: 1365750099675
          operations: 52
        }
        docs: {
          num_docs: 28104
          max_doc: 28242
          deleted_docs: 138
        }
        merges: {
          current: 0
          current_docs: 0
          current_size: 0b
          current_size_in_bytes: 0
          total: 191
          total_time: 1m
          total_time_in_millis: 60823
          total_docs: 2192291
          total_size: 1gb
          total_size_in_bytes: 1169679226
        }
        refresh: {
          total: 3450
          total_time: 8.7s
          total_time_in_millis: 8747
        }
        flush: {
          total: 29
          total_time: 11.5s
          total_time_in_millis: 11582
        }
      }
      {
        routing: {
          state: STARTED
          primary: false
          node: hUbZmGtMR-qFPr4h4ET_Xg
          relocating_node: null
          shard: 0
          index: tune
        }
        state: STARTED
        index: {
          size: 25.4mb
          size_in_bytes: 26658796
        }
        translog: {
          id: 1365750099676
          operations: 50
        }
        docs: {
          num_docs: 28104
          max_doc: 28773
          deleted_docs: 669
        }
        merges: {
          current: 0
          current_docs: 0
          current_size: 0b
          current_size_in_bytes: 0
          total: 191
          total_time: 8.9s
          total_time_in_millis: 8967
          total_docs: 151360
          total_size: 121.7mb
          total_size_in_bytes: 127708203
        }
        refresh: {
          total: 3445
          total_time: 8.5s
          total_time_in_millis: 8512
        }
        flush: {
          total: 30
          total_time: 9.5s
          total_time_in_millis: 9576
        }
      }
    ]
    1: [
      {
        routing: {
          state: STARTED
          primary: false
          node: 4klrp2F7TXqbqV2i2uJlrg
          relocating_node: null
          shard: 1
          index: tune
        }
        state: STARTED
        index: {
          size: 30.5mb
          size_in_bytes: 32065179
        }
        translog: {
          id: 1365750099763
          operations: 49
        }
        docs: {
          num_docs: 28006
          max_doc: 28156
          deleted_docs: 150
        }
        merges: {
          current: 0
          current_docs: 0
          current_size: 0b
          current_size_in_bytes: 0
          total: 193
          total_time: 53.8s
          total_time_in_millis: 53841
          total_docs: 2031945
          total_size: 877.1mb
          total_size_in_bytes: 919752655
        }
        refresh: {
          total: 3244
          total_time: 6.9s
          total_time_in_millis: 6922
        }
        flush: {
          total: 29
          total_time: 12.2s
          total_time_in_millis: 12245
        }
      }
      {
        routing: {
          state: STARTED
          primary: true
          node: hUbZmGtMR-qFPr4h4ET_Xg
          relocating_node: null
          shard: 1
          index: tune
        }
        state: STARTED
        index: {
          size: 31.6mb
          size_in_bytes: 33186132
        }
        translog: {
          id: 1365750099763
          operations: 50
        }
        docs: {
          num_docs: 28006
          max_doc: 28128
          deleted_docs: 122
        }
        merges: {
          current: 0
          current_docs: 0
          current_size: 0b
          current_size_in_bytes: 0
          total: 192
          total_time: 1m
          total_time_in_millis: 60375
          total_docs: 2246221
          total_size: 1gb
          total_size_in_bytes: 1136003705
        }
        refresh: {
          total: 3252
          total_time: 8.5s
          total_time_in_millis: 8591
        }
        flush: {
          total: 29
          total_time: 11.9s
          total_time_in_millis: 11967
        }
      }
    ]
    2: [
      {
        routing: {
          state: STARTED
          primary: false
          node: 4klrp2F7TXqbqV2i2uJlrg
          relocating_node: null
          shard: 2
          index: tune
        }
        state: STARTED
        index: {
          size: 29.8mb
          size_in_bytes: 31311783
        }
        translog: {
          id: 1365750099805
          operations: 53
        }
        docs: {
          num_docs: 28109
          max_doc: 28315
          deleted_docs: 206
        }
        merges: {
          current: 0
          current_docs: 0
          current_size: 0b
          current_size_in_bytes: 0
          total: 189
          total_time: 42.2s
          total_time_in_millis: 42284
          total_docs: 1850347
          total_size: 732.1mb
          total_size_in_bytes: 767707262
        }
        refresh: {
          total: 3186
          total_time: 6.8s
          total_time_in_millis: 6845
        }
        flush: {
          total: 30
          total_time: 10.5s
          total_time_in_millis: 10573
        }
      }
      {
        routing: {
          state: STARTED
          primary: true
          node: hUbZmGtMR-qFPr4h4ET_Xg
          relocating_node: null
          shard: 2
          index: tune
        }
        state: STARTED
        index: {
          size: 25.3mb
          size_in_bytes: 26615897
        }
        translog: {
          id: 1365750099804
          operations: 56
        }
        docs: {
          num_docs: 28109
          max_doc: 28799
          deleted_docs: 690
        }
        merges: {
          current: 0
          current_docs: 0
          current_size: 0b
          current_size_in_bytes: 0
          total: 188
          total_time: 8.8s
          total_time_in_millis: 8896
          total_docs: 145382
          total_size: 119.6mb
          total_size_in_bytes: 125410595
        }
        refresh: {
          total: 3189
          total_time: 7s
          total_time_in_millis: 7093
        }
        flush: {
          total: 29
          total_time: 11.2s
          total_time_in_millis: 11277
        }
      }
    ]
    3: [
      {
        routing: {
          state: STARTED
          primary: true
          node: 4klrp2F7TXqbqV2i2uJlrg
          relocating_node: null
          shard: 3
          index: tune
        }
        state: STARTED
        index: {
          size: 33mb
          size_in_bytes: 34651434
        }
        translog: {
          id: 1365750099726
          operations: 29
        }
        docs: {
          num_docs: 28044
          max_doc: 28150
          deleted_docs: 106
        }
        merges: {
          current: 0
          current_docs: 0
          current_size: 0b
          current_size_in_bytes: 0
          total: 182
          total_time: 1m
          total_time_in_millis: 65510
          total_docs: 2142019
          total_size: 1.1gb
          total_size_in_bytes: 1212362289
        }
        refresh: {
          total: 3198
          total_time: 6.4s
          total_time_in_millis: 6495
        }
        flush: {
          total: 29
          total_time: 11.5s
          total_time_in_millis: 11517
        }
      }
      {
        routing: {
          state: STARTED
          primary: false
          node: hUbZmGtMR-qFPr4h4ET_Xg
          relocating_node: null
          shard: 3
          index: tune
        }
        state: STARTED
        index: {
          size: 24.2mb
          size_in_bytes: 25376767
        }
        translog: {
          id: 1365750099726
          operations: 29
        }
        docs: {
          num_docs: 28044
          max_doc: 28079
          deleted_docs: 35
        }
        merges: {
          current: 0
          current_docs: 0
          current_size: 0b
          current_size_in_bytes: 0
          total: 181
          total_time: 1m
          total_time_in_millis: 63866
          total_docs: 2191165
          total_size: 1.2gb
          total_size_in_bytes: 1358617882
        }
        refresh: {
          total: 3190
          total_time: 7.9s
          total_time_in_millis: 7923
        }
        flush: {
          total: 29
          total_time: 12.3s
          total_time_in_millis: 12374
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

---

```
merges: {
  current: 0       <-------
  current_docs: 0  <-------
  current_size: 0b <-------
  current_size_in_bytes: 0 <-------
  total: 191
  total_time: 1m
  total_time_in_millis: 60823
  total_docs: 2192291
  total_size: 1gb <-------
  total_size_in_bytes: 1169679226
}
```

What is it?

Comment: Never mind, ES Team gave me a hint, i was refreshing my INDEX everytime I add new document.

Comment: I was facing the same problem because I had set refresh_interval as 30 in place of 30s :) So there were too many refreshes happening. Was about to ask the same question, but saw yours and my problem got solved. Thanks!!